# Testcafe - display steps while running tests

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

How do I display step by step information while running the test? Currently runs the command

> testcafe chrome .\test\customer.js

Generally speaking, need to see more info as to whats executed.

Answer (score 4):

For now, such a capability does not exist in TestCafe. But there is a corresponding [suggestion](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4001) in the TestCafe GitHub repository. You can subscribe on it to be informed about its status.